# Use of goto in this very specific case... alternatives?

Tags: c++, exception, flags, goto

I have a question about the possibile use of `goto` in a C++ code: I know that `goto` shall be avoided as much as possibile, but in this very particular case I'm having few difficulties to find good alternatives that avoid using multiple nested if-else and/or additional binary flags...
The code is like the following one (only the relevant parts are reported):

```
// ... do initializations, variable declarations, etc...

    while(some_flag) {
        some_flag=false;

        if(some_other_condition) {
            // ... do few operations (20 lines of code)

            return_flag=foo(input_args); // Function that can find an error, returning false
            if(!return_flag) {
                // Print error
                break; // jump out of the main while loop
            }

            // ... do other more complex operations
        }

        index=0;
        while(index<=SOME_VALUE) {
            // ... do few operations (about 10 lines of code)
            return_flag=foo(input_args); // Function that can find an error, returning false
            if(!return_flag) {
                goto end_here; // <- 'goto' statement
            }

            // ... do other more complex operations (including some if-else and the possibility to set some_flag to true or leave it to false
            // ... get a "value" to be compared with a saved one in order to decide whether to continue looping or not
            if(value<savedValue) {
                // Do other operations (about 20 lines of code)
                some_flag=true;
            }
            // ... handle 'index'
            it++; // Increse number of iterations
        }

        // ... when going out from the while loop, some other operations must be done, at the moment no matter the value of some_flag

        return_flag=foo(input_args);
        if(!return_flag) {
            goto end_here; // <- 'goto' statement
        }

        // ... other operations here
        // ... get a "value" to be compared with a saved one in order to decide whether to continue looping or not
        if(value<savedValue) {
            // Do other operations (about 20 lines of code)
            some_flag=true;
        }

        // Additional termination constraint
        if(it>MAX_ITERATIONS) {
            some_flag=false;
        }

        end_here:
        // The code after end_here checks for some_flag, and executes some operations that must always be done,
        // no matter if we arrive here due to 'goto' or due to normal execution.
    }
}

// ...
```

Every time `foo()` returns `false`, no more operations should be executed, and the code should execute the final operations as soon as possible. Another requirement is that this code, mainly the part inside the `while(index<=SOME_VALUE)` shall run as fast as possible to try to have a good overall performance.

Is using a 'try/catch' block, with the `try{}` including lots of code inside (while, actually, the function foo() can generate errors only when called, that is in two distinct points of the code only) a possibile alternative? Is is better in this case to use different 'try/catch' blocks? 
Are there other better alternatives?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: wrap the clean-up in another function and call that + return instead of goto? Your function seems to be very long anyways

Comment: I doubt whether an `if` statement is necessary slower than the goto; who knows, they may end up as very similar machine code. I would also recommend breaking the function up into logical sub-units (i.e. functions). That makes the flow clearer, which is of the essence for maintenance. If you are concerned about performance, these functions can be made inline! (Perhaps with the keyword, and certainly with the proper compiler settings.)

Comment: Yes, it is about 250 lines of code total. The main problem is also that this code is inside a specific function (critical for the simulation) inside a particular OMNeT++ library, and it is used for an OMNeT simulation... The "cleanup" code actually is used to properly save a "solution" file (using Win32 API) and to delete all the temporary files, and that's why it shall be always executed if I'm not wrong: remaining with an "usaved" solution file could cause a complete simulation failure.

Comment: Wrapping the clean-up inside a function could be a solution, though... but since this is done only through Win32 API calls and it actually does not require any extra parameter (at least, in this implementation), would it be good, from a "coding style" point of view, to add a void clean(void) function?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Thanks for your comment. The fact of avoiding 'if' was not related to performance, in general, but only to avoid extra nested if-else that could have made the code, that is already complex, a bit less readable.
Thanks also for the suggestion of breaking the code inside inline functions. The only problem may be about having to pass them quite a lot of parameters, but it is surely something to try to make the code more readable in general.

Comment: @es483 "Quite a  lot of params": Sometimes people create objects to pass (as pointers, usually) which combine the information of several parameters in a struct. E.g. GridBagConstraints  for a Java GridbagLayout). The more places use a similar set of parameters the more rewarding this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three obvious choices:

1. Stick with `goto`
2. Associate the cleanup code with the destructor of some RAII class.  (You can probably write it as the delete for a `std::unique_ptr` as a lambda.)
3. Rename your function as `foo_internal`, and change it to just `return`. Then write the cleanup in a new `foo` function which calls `foo_internal`

So:

```
return_t foo(Args...) {
    const auto result = foo_internal(Args..);
    // cleanup
    return result;
}
```

In general, your function looks too long, and needs decomposing into smaller bits.

Comment: Thanks! Solution 3 seems a very good one to be implemented in my case in order to avoid gotos, and to mantain also a similar code structure.
Splitting the function into smaller bits also would be useful to try to increase the overall readability, but it would require for example inline functions with a good number of parameters (since every part of the code uses flags and strings updated during execution of other parts of the code)... making these flags as local global varibales would help, though, I think. I'll surely try to decompose the whole function!

Comment: "every part of the code uses flags and strings updated during execution of other parts of the code" has a code smell :-). Ideally code would be composed of loosely coupled parts; each one has a limited set of inputs and strives to produce a result (as opposed to performing some side effect). What you describe is close coupling over long distances; as you are just experiencing, such code makes maintenance and feature extension difficult.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is to use another *dummy* loop and `break` like so

```
 int state = FAIL_STATE;

 do {
     if(!operation()) {
         break;
     }

     if(!other_operation()) {
         break;
     }
     // ...
     state = OK_STATE;
 } while(false);

 // check for state here and do necessary cleanups
```

That way you can avoid deep nesting levels in your code beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

It's C++! Use exceptions for non-local jumps:

```
try {
    if(some_result() < threshold) throw false;
}
catch(bool) {
    handleErrors();
}
// Here follows mandatory cleanup for both sucsesses and failures
```

Comment: `throw false` looks horrible.

Comment: No more than any other throw. :-)

Comment: Only recommended  if it is indeed an exceptional situation.